# how to translate math espression in a string to integer

Tags: php, math, eval

For example I have a statement:

```
$var = '2*2-3+8'; //variable type is string
```

How to make it to be equal `9` ?

Comment: Care to pay attention to the "Related" section of the page? A duplocate of [how to evaluate formula passed as string in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015242/how-to-evaluate-formula-passed-as-string-in-php)

Comment: ok, sorry I found also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057320/php-function-to-evaluate-string-like-2-1-as-arithmetic-2-1-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this page](http://www.pfz.nl/wiki/invoer-validatie/#regular-expressions-is-het-een-geldige-berekening), a very awesome (simple) calculation validation regular expression, written by [Richard van Velzen](http://liefcoden.nl/blog/). Once you have that, and it matches, you can rest assured that you can use eval over the string. Always make sure the input is validated before using eval!

```
<?php
$regex = '{
    \A        # the absolute beginning of the string
    \h*        # optional horizontal whitespace
    (        # start of group 1 (this is called recursively)
    (?:
        \(        # literal (

        \h*
        [-+]?        # optionally prefixed by + or -
        \h*

        # A number
        (?: \d* \. \d+ | \d+ \. \d* | \d+) (?: [eE] [+-]? \d+ )?

        (?:
            \h*
            [-+*/]        # an operator
            \h*
            (?1)        # recursive call to the first pattern.
        )?

        \h*
        \)        # closing )

        |        # or: just one number

        \h*
        [-+]?
        \h*

        (?: \d* \. \d+ | \d+ \. \d* | \d+) (?: [eE] [+-]? \d+ )?
    )

    # and the rest, of course.
    (?:
        \h*
        [-+*/]
        \h*
        (?1)
    )?
    )
    \h*

    \z        # the absolute ending of the string.
}x';

$var = '2*2-3+8';

if( 0 !== preg_match( $regex, $var ) ) {
    $answer = eval( 'return ' . $var . ';' );
    echo $answer;
}
else {
    echo "Invalid calculation.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is find or write a parser function that can properly read equations and actually calculate the outcome. In a lot of languages this can be implemented by use of a Stack, you should have to look at things like postfix and infix parsers and the like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: not to mention that there are tons of ready-made parsers right here in stackoverflow answers

Comment: Col. Shrapnel is probably right, I didn't have the time to look for ready-made parsers, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$string_with_expression = '2+2';
eval('$eval_result = ' . $string_with_expression)`;
```

$eval_result - is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

There is [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function

But you can't apply direct to **$var**

For parser Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239136/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-php)