# How to validate integer values to avoid SQL injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, integer, sql-injection

The best way to avoid SQL injection for defined value type such as numbers, is to validate the value; since it is easier to do so comparing with mysqli preparation. In PHP, we can do this by.

```
1. if(!is_numeric($value)) {$value=0;}
2. $value=floatval($value);
3. $value=intval($value);
4. $value=$value * 1;
```

What is the most reliable one? or a better idea?

**UPDATE:** Although I have stated in the original question, most of folks emphasized the usefulness of parameterized queries. Definitely, it is the most efficient way to avoid SQL injection. But when we can simply validate an integer numeric value; IMHO, there is no need to parametrization.

Comment: The best way to avoid SQL injection is to use parameterized SQL statements.

Comment: `$value=intval($value)`;
Or
`(int)$value`;

Comment: Yes if you make everything right, there is no need for parametrization, and parametrization is not always possible as well. However you can choose any tool that does the job, `is_numeric` and `floatval` is not part of it if you look for integer values (!).

Comment: If string might contain leading whitespace that you wish to ignore, use `$value = (int)trim($value);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For integers and floats you can use this if you don't want to do a parameterised query.

```
$clean_number = (int)$value;

$clean_number = (float)$value;
```

These are actually casting the value as `int` and `float`, this is faster than `intval()` and `floatval()` for example because it does not suffer the function overhead.

Comment: @Ali there is actually nothing nice in function overheads. And nothing "faster" as well.

Comment: Benchmark of `(int)` vs `intval()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239136/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-php

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ironically, your comment doesn't make sense, but thanks for the downvote. Tests show the cast is faster than `intval()`.

Comment: These tests make no sense. They are a light year far away from the **real life.** Keep you playing in the imaginary sandbox.

Comment: @YourCommonSense if you could show me a 'real life' example where `intval($num)` is faster than `(int)$num`, I would gladly edit my answer. When you make claims like that, you should back it up by pointing to some sort of research so people can make up their own minds instead of trying to force your views on people.

Comment: I haven't said that intval($num) is faster than (int)$num. They are equal. Take whatever real life script which is using int casting, create 2 version of it, (int) and intval() one, run apache benchmark on both versions. Try to find the difference.

Comment: If string might contain leading whitespace that you wish to ignore, use `$clean_number = (int)trim($value);`

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use [**the filter extension**](http://php.net/filter):

```
$id = filter_var($id, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

You should **definitively** go for parameterized queries.

Comment: Its worth mentioning pro/con of using sanitize filter. Pro: If there is a number in the input, it will find it. Con: Is that really what you want given a garbage string? - the more restricted behaviour of `(int)` (or `intval()`) is often more appropriate - unusual strings simply become `0`. HOWEVER, AFAIK, `(int)` doesn't `trim` whitespace, so the alternative to filter, when don't want to strip all garbage, probably should be `(int)trim($value);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `intval()` to coerce a value to integer. The most reliable way to avoid SQL injection is to use parameterised queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id');
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Yes. Because you don't have dozens of different filtering functions to know. You create your SQL request then give it its params.

Comment: @Arkh it is not about different filtering functions. it's about **this very code**. Which is a mile far away from being easy.

Comment: @Arkh if you want to talk of "different filtering functions", there are "dozen" different binding types as well.

Comment: The filtering part of this code is the prepare / bindparam lines. All other things are connecting to the db and getting the request result which you'll have to do even with the mysql functions and (int) casting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a **seasoned** advise, you have to change your mind. Completely.

The thing that being your main concern, in fact, is the most negligible thing in the world. You may use one way or another with not a slightest difference. There is no "most reliable" way. That's just several ways of doing the same.

On the other hand, "there is no need to parametrization" is a grave delusion.
Parameterized queries can do any good only if used explicitly, throughout whole site, with no exceptions. One exception can spoil all the defense.

Not to mention that parameterized query can make your life much, much easier.
Prepared statements are not such an ugly code that propagated on this site by some enthusiasts. It's actually quick and neat way of writing **safe** code.
Say, the code that took cetver a dozen lines can be done in just **one**:

```
$data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :placeholder:",$id);
```

and be perfectly safe
without ugly manual binding.
without error-prone manual casting.

Another example to show you the power of *placeholders*

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE tstamp BETWEEN ?i AND ?i AND flag=?s AND IN in (?a)";
$data = $db->getAll($sql,$min,$max,$flag,$array_of_ids);
```

Two lines.

I am not too good with PDO but it would be like a *dozen* lines of code even without connect

```
$in  = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($array_of_ids), '?'));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE tstamp BETWEEN ? AND ? AND flag=? AND id IN ($in)"
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $min);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $max);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $flag);
foreach ($array_of_ids as $i => $id) {
  $stmt->bindValue(($i+4), $id);
}
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And comparable amount with your current manual casting.

This is actually the power of *programming.*
One can write *a program* to do all the dirty job for them.
An approach almost never seen on this site.

*Sapienti sat*

Comment: very interesting approach to make prepared statement a constant culture of coding. I really appreciate your way to use prepare statement in one line code; but I wonder how to use it in PHP mysqli?

Comment: One have to invent a *type-hinted placeholder* for this. the query actually have to be like `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?i"`, where `?i` is a placeholder and `i` is a type. Some parsing have to be done to get the placeholders and their types from the query. After that all data can be easily binded/substituted according to the placeholder type.

Comment: Incidentally, note that the code you've replaced from cetver's example only replaces _four_ lines, not 12. You didn't bother writing the other code.

Comment: @sarnold well spotted! That's the problem with answers on this site. They **never** encourage good code styling or a slightest abstraction, **never show a better approach!** Face the reality, **look at the questions** - the codes always contains the same ugly raw API function calls. Even connection code seldom separated! And it's real codes right from the production. You all have an excuse for yourself - "it's just a demo!" but you have no idea that this "demo" always copy/pasted and used as is. So, it's 13, not 4.

Comment: @sarnold here is a dozen for your pleasure ;)

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Thank you for removing the offensive line from your answer +1.

Comment: @M.Babcock get your vote back. There is nothing offensive in that line. Try to be not too touchy about the things, never intended to be offensive.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Whether you saw it or not, it spurred conversation on meta (hence the mass downvoting). The vote probably would have went to some undeserving schmuck anyway. Enjoy!

Comment: I don't care about voting in general and mass downvoting in particular. For the meaning of the words I trust the books I read, not conversations on whatever metas.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Perhaps, but you must care about sharing your vast knowledge if you took the time to write out such a complete and thorough answer. It really is a good answer. It's too bad fewer people will read it and take it seriously with a negative vote count. Certainly if that didn't matter to you, you wouldn't have answered in the first place.

Comment: @M.Babcock there are several problems with this. First, the answer will never be read anyway. Take whatever question from 2011 - it seldom has more than 30-40 views, all from the time it has been written. It is abyss. Every answer sunks forever. So, nothing to care of too much. Next, even without all that mess, my answer had no more votes than whatever rubbish answer above. Thats another problem - a good answer never can be distinguished from the bad one by votes. That's core problems of the stackoverflow site, not mine.

Comment: @Your: Excellent! I agree with your sentiment _They never encourage good code styling or a slightest abstraction, never show a better approach!_ I know I'm guilty of this too, but I long ago saw you respond something along the lines of, _I'm not going to answer the question as asked, but instead the question that should have been asked_, and I've kept it to heart since then.

Comment: @sarnold thanks for the understanding. I just rethinked the raw code though, it could be actually 2 times shorter, 6 lines only, if we just pass an array of values to the `execute()`. Just for sake of impartiality - I am not going to abandon my idea of abstraction :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function, mysql_real_escape_string()  to espace special characters, but what you are doing its fine to protect an sqli attack.

Comment: 'mysql_real_escape_string()' is not reliable at all. This is the reason that parametrized mysqli is actually needed.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string being useless for the numbers.