# Are common examples of SQL injection misguided?

Tags: php, sql, security, mysqli, sql-injection

Definitely, SQL injection is the most serious security issue for web applications, but I think, many blogs and tutorials are misleading by exaggerating the unrealistic examples (or maybe I'm wrong). The common example is when entering value of

```
; DELETE FROM ...
```

This is merely theory based on the basics of SQL. When in real world using `PHP` for example, `mysql_query()` or `mysqli->query()` will only execute the first SQL query. Adding anything after `;` will result in syntax error.

Is it possible to make a WRITE action by SQL injection on a `SELECT` query in `PHP`?

**UPDATE:** My point is to clarify if it is possible to make a second query in PHP. Not discussing the necessity of preventing SQL injection or how to do this. The ultimate solution is obviously prepared statements.

Comment: The obligatory http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: In a worst case scenario you could use mysql's `SELECT … INTO OUTFILE` command and write arbitrary files on the server. And then you're pretty much screwed. Besides, _writing_ is not the only security issue, _reading_ is at least as bad. Imagine attackers can get hold of private information/passwords/email addresses/etc.

Comment: @Dr.biziclop The ultimate solution for preventing SQL injection to prepare statements. However, my question is not how to prevent.

Comment: Hi, this question would fit well at IT Security stackexchange. I've flagged it for migration.

Comment: With the right tools, I can shoot down a rocket. Exaggerated? Not. When it comes to hackers, they are always striving to be one step ahead.

Comment: Prepared statements are definitely not the ultimate protection. Anyway, I see no point in the question at all. I see no practical reason for asking it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Then what is the best way to prevent SQL statement, if prepared statement is not?

Comment: use prepared statement for the data and whitelisting for the other query parts.

Comment: @YourCommonSense you're a great programmer but with bad memory: "there is no need to parametrization" is a grave delusion.
Parameterized queries can do any good only if used explicitly, throughout whole site, with no exceptions. One exception can spoil all the defense. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9681303/943340

Comment: Your latter correction to the title made it sensible at the very least. "Are common examples of SQL injection misguided?" is a good question and the answer is yes. Unfortunately, it was too late. Anyway, it's not that important question. A bad example doesn't mean that the problem doesn't exist. As for the quotation you cited, it is missed it's goal my a mile. Read my other comment again. And try to understand it.

Comment: +1 yes you are correct.  most people,  including XKCD,  don't have a functional knowledge of sql injection.  They just read it in a textbook and never tried it.   Try reading "Hackpoofing mysql" by nccgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Ali, SQL Injection is a common concept , not only restricted to PHP, although its not a hard and fast rule that , these actions can be executed thses cannot be, but yes it gives hackers a backdoor entry to your db schema insight, which in any way is dangerous, not only alterations, but is someone by any means get to see any of the information cna be dangerous.

Comment: I've seen tutorial exclusively for `PHP` with example of second `DELETE` query. Of course, it is not only PHP and other scripting languages have also implemented such limitations for single query.

Answer (score 1):

> My point is to clarify if it is possible to make a second query in PHP.

In some circumstances - Yes.
It doesn't matter though, because injections aren't limited to adding second queries.

this latter question, however, contradicts with question title, which reads

> Isn't SQL injection exaggerated?

and answer is definitely NO.
because

> Is it possible to make a WRITE action by SQL injection on a SELECT query in PHP?

No matter if it's possible or not - a SELECT query can be no less disastrous than INSERT/UPDATE

Comment: How to make the second query in PHP?

Comment: use mysqli_multi_query, LOL :)

Comment: We are talking about unwanted injection, not how the coder can do this.

Comment: We are talking of the question you asked. It was "How to make the second query in PHP" and you've got the answer, but not satisfied again. You're a capricious one ;) That's because your question have no practical reason I believe.

Comment: Then you're a player with words. Though my question was "Is it possible to make a WRITE action by SQL injection on a SELECT query in PHP?"

Comment: Well, my answer was "Yes, if you're using mysqli_multi_query()". What's wrong with it?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Frankly, you are deliberately arguing with Ali uselessly just to bash him. What OP asks is a good question and I think people are misunderstanding him!

Comment: @Shubham well, if you have better understanding of his question, would you please translate it for us?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Certainly, a coder will use mysql_query() to implement DB operations (if ignorant about PDO and mysqli). So if string is not escaped, is it possible to make a second query if the same function is used?

Comment: @Shubham well, if he wanted to know about using mysql_query(), he had to ask it. But he asked about PHP in general.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Yes, it was a mistake on his part but as comments suggest, Thats what he wants.

Comment: @Shubham even corrected this way the question doesn't make sense anyway.