# Converting string to number

Tags: php, string, integer

It seems to be a very simple question, I use "0888" as my input value example here. I have researched for a while and tried different ways, such as

```
(int) "0888";
intval("0888");
floatval("0888");
settype("0888", "integer");
```

Unfortunately none of them seems to work.
Reference [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239136/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-php)
Reference [2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)
Reference [3](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?142574-convert-string-to-int)

```
$num = $_POST['postcode'];

if((1000 <= $num && $num <= 1999) || (2000 <= $num && $num <= 2599) || (2619 <= $num && $num <= 2898) || (2921 <= $num && $num <= 2999)){
    $state = "NSW";
}
elseif((0200 <= $num && $num <= 0299) || (2600 <= $num && $num <= 2618) || (2900 <= $num && $num <= 2920)){
    $state = "ACT";
}
elseif((3000 <= $num && $num <= 3999) || (8000 <= $num && $num <= 8999)){
    $state = "VIC";
}
elseif((4000 <= $num && $num <= 4999) || (9000 <= $num && $num <= 9999)){
    $state = "QLD";
}
elseif((5000 <= $num && $num <= 5799) || (5800 <= $num && $num <= 5999)){
    $state = "SA";
}
elseif((6000 <= $num && $num <= 6797) || (6800 <= $num && $num <= 6999)){
    $state = "WA";
}
elseif((7000 <= $num && $num <= 7799) || (7800 <= $num && $num <= 7999)){
    $state = "TAS";
}
elseif((0800 <= $num && $num <= 0899) || (0900 <= $num && $num <= 0999)){
    $state = "NT";
}
else {
    $state = "Can not find this postcode record";
}
```

If I `echo $state`I expect to see NT but actually I see "Can not find this postcode record" instead. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Most languages interpret strings starting with 0 as octal representations

Comment: Post codes are not numbers, especially if they hold a value that is not purely numeric, like a "leading 0".

Comment: So what is the fix? @flup

Comment: you need to add a bit more code, maybe you are assigning a variable wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0299` is the [*octal* notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) of a number, which is very different from the *decimal* 299. In fact, `9` is invalid in octal and `0299` just has the value 2. Try `echo 0299;`, then `echo 0123;`.

If you're treating postcodes as numbers at all, you should strip leading 0s from it and don't use leading 0s in companions:

```
$code = ltrim($_POST['postcode'], '0');

... $code <= 299 ...
```

Comment: You said it, that is actually my problem, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use trim then ltrim for zeros, the second parameter allows using any characters you want to trim.

```
<?php
$num = $_POST['postcode'];
$num = ltrim( trim($_POST['postcode'], ' ') , '0'); //trim SPACES or ZERO
```

If you are sure the number comes in the left you can use ltrim(

```
// Just to be sure, finally reconvert it to (int)
$num = (int) $num;
```

Comment: Actually you should try to trim on the right too, if this is from a POST/textboxes, sometimes user type in spaces, zeros.

Comment: Actually you should try to trim spaces on the right too, if this is from a POST/textboxes, sometimes user type in spaces, zeros.
When we examined a large db before, a lot of users had inserted spaces then, probably by mistake.

Comment: If someone entered 9000 and you trimmed all the zeroes to the right it would then become 9 which is essentially 8991 less than 9000, how is that the same?

Answer (score 0):

[intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) will by default parse your strings base 10 so `$num = intval("0888");` will correctly parse the string to 888. No need to trim.

The [integer literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) in your if statements, however, get interpreted as octal numbers. Remove the leading zeros there:

```
[...] elseif((800 <= $num && $num <= 899)  [...]
```