# Convert String to int php

Tags: php, string, numbers

The google books api returns a volumeid for each book. This volumeid is string like this

```
AZ5J6B1-4BoC
UvK1Slvkz3MC
OBM3AAAAIAAJ
```

So there are capital letters , small letters, characters like dash(-) underscore(_) etc

So is there a library that converts these characters to integer?

Also can I just convert the string to certain number like

```
[A-Z]=[0-25]
[a-z]=[26-50]
[special characters like -,_,]=[51-...]
```

Will the above self-cooked script good or are there certain standard functions in php that do the job?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239136/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

```
function num($text)
        {
        $num=null;

        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++)
        {
        $num =$num.ord($text[$i]);
        }

        return($num);
        }
```

Example 10183491225753109122105505667. It is 30 digit long number but if you want a unique number then this is it.

Answer (score 1):

For this there is no standard function for this. We have write customize code for this.

```
 <?php
    function AsciiToInt($char){
    $success = "";
        if(strlen($char) == 1)
            return "char(".ord($char).")";
        else{
            for($i = 0; $i < strlen($char); $i++){
                if($i == strlen($char) - 1)
                    $success = $success.ord($char[$i]);
                else
                    $success = $success.ord($char[$i]).",";
            }
            return "char(".$success.")";
        }
    }
    echo AsciiToInt("<br>");//outputs char(60,98,114,62)
    ?>
```