# Get value of a mysql record and show in drop down

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql entry as an integer 1 to 10. I want to display the result pre selected in a drop down. I am using -

```
<select name="Sleeps">
<?php
 $sleeps = $row['Sleeps'];

 $selectedId = array(1, 2, 3);
 $selection = array(
        1 => "1",
        2 => "2",
        3 => "3" );

 foreach($selection as $value){
    $text = $value;
    $selected = '';
    if ($selectedID == $sleeps) {
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo '<option value="'.$text.'" selected="'.$selected.'">'.$text.'</option>';
 }
?>
</select>
```

This nearly works as I get -

```
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
```

But all options have selected="selected" and i just want the value I have in my db selected which I believe should just be 'selected' text like -

2

Please help I am new to this

Comment: who is `$sleeps`?, make a `echo` of the values of `$selectedID` and `$sleeps`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is types mistake. Try using "===" or if this rows is text convert to int
[How contert text to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239136/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($selectedID == $sleeps) {
    $selected = 'selected';
}
```

Should be

```
if ($text == $sleeps) {
    $selected = 'selected';
}
```

`selectedID` isn't defined anywhere, however, `selectedId` is, and if you want it to be sleected for any number in the array, use

```
if (in_array($sleeps, $selectedID)) {
    $selected = 'selected';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this the main problem i have is that I am getting  selected="selected" in each option where I need just the word selected against one of them - the same as the value from the database. thanks.

Comment: I have fixed this now I wasnt getting a value for $sleeps