# $GET['id'] is 19, (int) $GET['id'] is 0 ??? in internet explorer 11

Tags: php, internet-explorer, casting, get

I am trying to typecast a GET variable to int in internet explorer 11 (only) without success

URL ...&project_id=19

$tt= $_GET['project_id'] ;    is 19 in debugger, as expected

$tt= (int) $_GET['project_id'] ;   is 0

strlen($tt) is 2

mb_str_encoding($tt) is ASCII

In FF, the typecast works fine, same in older internet explorer.

anyone has ideas what is going on?

Klaus

Comment: This has nothing to do with browsers.  I'd also recommend you use `intval` instead of casting to an int.

Comment: @GigaWatt: any reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using cast. Instead use `intval`
It's a bit slower than casting , [see benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/239173/1494393), but in my experience safer.

Comment: "but in my experience safer" --- could you please elaborate? What would you say if I tell you they both use the same code internally?

Answer (score -1):

oneneeds to reconvert from ASCII to UTF-8.

the following works:

$tt= (int) mb_convert_encoding($_GET['project_id'], 'UTF-8'  );

Klaus

Comment: `19` is an ASCII safe string. In UTF-8 it's encoded with **exactly the same** bytes.