# Php String to Integer conversion gives 0 as result

Tags: php, string, casting, int, type-conversion

When I try to convert a number as a string to an integer, The value changes to 0.

I did a preg_match and picked out a number value which as an output of preg_match is in a string datatype.

That is, When i tried to extract the number 7123 in the following xml data, 
    `<Count> 7123 </Count>` using preg_match, I got the value 7123 as a string. [Used gettype function]. When I am checking if its 0 or anyother value, I need to convert it to integer datatype just to compare the values farely. So i do intval("7123") or intval($count) to get the integer value. But when I echo the value, its 0. Read few blogs online and one said this type of a thing happens when the string value is non-printable. Can someone help me understand this and help me solve it?

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple once you know how to convert a string to integer:

```
$str = "7123";
$val = (int) $str;

echo $val + 1;
```

result: **7124**

This is not the only way to convert strings to integers, but it's been [**proven to be the fastest**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239136/fastest-way-to-convert-string-to-integer-in-php).

Comment: Nope. It still gives me the same 0 as result

Comment: @Vignesh, What is the output if you `echo var_dump($count);` or the variable you are setting? (do it before trying to do the conversion).

Comment: The output is `int(0)`

Comment: With `(int)$str` step, the result was `int(0)`. Without that it is `string(24) "48"`

Comment: This is the code: `preg_match("/(\S+)<\/Count>/i",$handle,$match1);
$totalcount=$match1[1];` $handle has the xml data and $match1 is the array of results. The value is in $totalcount. When I gave `echo var_dump($totalcount)` The result was `string(24) "48"`

Comment: Change your regex pattern to this: `preg_match("/(\d+).+\/Count>/i",$handle,$match1);`

Comment: If there is a value present it picks up the value. But if there is 0 in between the Count tags, It picks up a random value of 55. Dont know why

Comment: This is the sample data

    `<eSearchResult>
    <Count>0</Count>
    <RetMax>0</RetMax>
    <RetStart>0</RetStart>
    <IdList/>
    <TranslationSet/>
    <TranslationStack>
    <TermSet>
    <Term>PONT[tiab]</Term>
    <Field>tiab</Field>
    <Count>552</Count>
    <Explode>N</Explode>
    </TermSet>
    <TermSet>
    <Term>Carboplatin[tiab]</Term>
    <Field>tiab</Field>
    <Count>10551</Count>
    <Explode>N</Explode>
    </TermSet>
    <OP>AND</OP>
    </TranslationStack>
    <QueryTranslation>PONT[tiab] AND Carboplatin[tiab]</QueryTranslation>
    </eSearchResult>

Comment: Okay, I see what is going on. Are you only trying to capture the first <count> value? also, post your code in your question next time.

Comment: Yes I am.. the first count value. Sorry. will post the code as well.

Comment: Change your regex to this: `preg_match_all("/<Count\D+(\d+)\D+\/Count>/i",$handle,$match1);` — It will grab all values in an array, but you can use it just as you did before, with one slight change `$totalcount=$match1[1][0];`

Comment: Thanks. When I try printing the array using a forloop, I get this as n error. `Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/search.php on line 83
Array `

Comment: `preg_match_all("/<Count\D+(\d+)\D+\/Count>/i",$handle,$match1);
for ($i=0; $i<count($match1);$i++){ echo $match1[$i] }`

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after `echo $match1[$i]`; but since it's an array you need `print_r($match1[$i]);` you can also do `print_r($match1[1]);` without the loop, it gives the same result.

Comment: I'm having the same problem `string to int casting returns 0` and have no clue how to handle it. The above solution just adds 1 to existing 0.

Comment: @ToughGuy: Post a new question with your problem and someone will surely be able to tell you what is going on...